# Insert data into table and if already present bring it to the top SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, audio, android-music-player

I'm making a "Recently played" playlist in my music app. I have created a database for storing the info related to songs. What my current code does is whenever I play a song it add it the database and I can successfully display it. But the problem is when I play the same song twice, the database isn't updating. 
Example, I played song A,song B, song C, song D respectively. Then it will display song A, song B, song C, song D. But if i play song A,song B, song C, song D and song B again respectively. Then it again displays the same(song A, song B, song C, song D). But what I want is: song A, song C, song D, song B. It should update and show the latest song played, that is what i meant. I can't figure out how to do it.

Code for table creation:

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ARTIST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DURATION + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ART + " TEXT"
            + ");";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

}
```

Code for getting and displaying the data :

```
   public ArrayList<SongInfoModel> getRecentlyPlayed(){

    ArrayList<SongInfoModel> rpList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery  = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        do{

            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            String SongName = cursor.getString(1);
            String artistName = cursor.getString(2);
            long dur = cursor.getLong(3);
            String Art = cursor.getString(4);

            SongInfoModel sh = new SongInfoModel(id,SongName,artistName,dur,null,Art);

            rpList.add(sh);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return rpList;
```

Code for adding data:

```
 public void addSong(SongInfoModel songInfoModel){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, songInfoModel.getSongID());
        values.put(KEY_NAME, songInfoModel.getSongName());
        values.put(KEY_ARTIST, songInfoModel.getArtistName());
        values.put(KEY_DURATION, songInfoModel.getDuration());
        values.put(KEY_ART, songInfoModel.getAlbumIDArtwork());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();

    }
```

Comment: try this Collections.reverse(yourList);

Comment: you have list of song which is in String array then you which is played in `media player`.make another list and add it in .

Answer (score 0):

Change your table query trailing semicolon inside the create query **")";**

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ARTIST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DURATION + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ART + " TEXT"
            + ")";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

Comment: No difference, it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to my mind is to add one field which indicates the number of times played, lets say KEY_TIMES.

When adding a song check

- If its already there, if it is there update the field
- If not add it with the field at default value.

Finally, for getting the values just use the same query, but ordering by this new field:

```
String selectQuery  = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + KEY_TIMES;
```

To create the table use:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = 
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "(" +
        KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + 
        KEY_ARTIST + " TEXT," +
        KEY_DURATION + " INTEGER," +
        KEY_LAST_PLAYED + " INTEGER," +
        KEY_TIMES + " INTEGER," +
        KEY_ART + " TEXT" + ");";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE); 
}
```

And then when you are going to add song, make a query with the ID you want to add, if the query returns an entry in the table, make a query to update the KEY_TIMES field. If it does not return an entry, make the insert as you are making it right now, but adding the new field. (Can't provide code for this right now)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a lastPlayed date field to your code. So it looks like this.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = 
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ "(" +
        KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
        KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + 
        KEY_ARTIST + " TEXT," +
        KEY_DURATION + " INTEGER," +
        KEY_LAST_PLAYED + " INTEGER," +
        KEY_ART + " TEXT" + ");";

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE); 
}
```

Your code for displaying the data will look like this and make sure to order by last played:

```
public ArrayList<SongInfoModel getRecentlyPlayed() { 
    ArrayList<SongInfoModel> rpList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + KEY_LAST_PLAYED + " ASC;";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){ 
        do{ 
            long id = cursor.getLong(0); 
            String SongName = cursor.getString(1); 
            String artistName = cursor.getString(2); 
            long dur = cursor.getLong(3); 
            String Art = cursor.getString(5); 
            SongInfoModel sh = new SongInfoModel(id,SongName,artistName,dur,null,Art); 
            rpList.add(sh);
       }while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
} 
return rpList;
}
```

And your code for adding data:

```
public void addSong(SongInfoModel songInfoModel){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
    values.put(KEY_ID, songInfoModel.getSongID()); 
    values.put(KEY_NAME, songInfoModel.getSongName()); 
    values.put(KEY_ARTIST, songInfoModel.getArtistName()); 
    values.put(KEY_DURATION, songInfoModel.getDuration()); 
    values.put(KEY_LAST_PLAYED, new Date().getTime());
    values.put(KEY_ART, songInfoModel.getAlbumIDArtwork()); 
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values); 
    db.close();
}
```

This combination will get you the data in the order last played.

Comment: values.put(KEY_LAST_PLAYED, new Date().getTime());
Is it an inbuilt class in android? new Date()??

Comment: I think it's straight up a Java class

Comment: So it should be present, no need to bring new libraries for it.  What the command does is give you a representation in milliseconds of the current time and date based on the local device clock.

Comment: BTW I typed this on my phone, so I couldn't make sure there are no mistakes. If the order is reversed try DSC instead of ASC in the Order by part.

Comment: it is giving me an error : no column exists KEY_LAST_PLAYED

Comment: Did you delete your old table, to make sure the Create function runs again?

Comment: It is still giving me the same error. I uninstalled the app, cleared app data, cache..and even incremented the database version ,still no luck

Comment: Is there any other way to add column to the table?

Comment: What are the values of your key constants?

Comment: private static final String TABLE_NAME = "RECENTLYPLAYED";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "ID";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "SONG";
    private static final String KEY_ARTIST = "ARTIST";
    private static final String KEY_DURATION ="DURATION";
    private static final String KEY_LAST_PLAYED ="LPLAYED";
    private static final String KEY_ART = "ART";

Comment: private static final int DATABASE_VER = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MUSICANADB";

Comment: Is the error when you try to write or when you read? If it's when you read try to search for the correct syntax to implement order by.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it's ASC; or just ASC without the semicolon.

Comment: it is not sorting according to time and its DESC.